# Unable to assign Allow View Knowledge permission to a Permission Set

Tags: permission-sets, knowledge

In moving from Profiles to Permission Sets, I wanted to assign the `Allow View Knowledge` permission to a Permission Set under `App Permissions`

But the permission is disabled in the editor[image]

How do I enable this permission in a Permission Set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this permission `Allow View Knowledge` is not supported if your Permission Set has a License = `Salesforce`.

**Workarounds**

- Use a Permission Set with license = `blank` or `Salesforce Platform` (if relevant) OR ..
- Recognize that OOTB profile `Minimum Access - Salesforce` has `View All Knowledge` set to TRUE and it can't be edited. It is not clear to me that SFDC will remove this permission from this Profile as they encourage us to move to permission-less Profiles (originally scheduled for Spring 26 but now postponed TBD)